# Create new node in linked list with data type "struct" for data

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc

```
typedef struct class
{
   ...
}Class;

typedef struct node
{
    Class data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node* newNode()
{
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp -> data = malloc(sizeof(Class));
    temp -> next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

The compiler says there is a problem with the line: `temp -> data = malloc(sizeof(Class));`, specifically "incompatible types in assignment".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that `data` is a `Class` but you're trying to assign it a `Class*`.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem, so how would I fix it?

Comment: In the struct definition, change ```Class data;``` to ```Class* data;```

Comment: @sdfrn42, better still might be to just do nothing.  Your `struct node` has a `Class` as a member, so the space allocated for a node *already includes* space for a Class.  You don't need to allocate that separately.  Change the member to a `Class *` only if that's what you actually want to have.

Comment: Will do in a couple mins when it lets me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I didn't actually think of that... What exactly changes when i change it to ```Class *```?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, @sdfrn42.  I mean, the difference is that in one case the node contains a `Class`, whereas in the other it contains (only) a pointer to a `Class` that lives somewhere else.  There are applications for both, so I can't tell you which one you want.

Comment: @sdfrn42 Please do not include "thank you" comments on Stack Overflow. They're (sadly) frowned upon here.